# Agile: tasks for testing or testing tasks?

Tags: testing, task, agile, user-stories

I was wondering what does the standard recommend as best practice in this scenario:

When creating tasks for a user story we usually have development/design/documentation/testing tasks. Should we create a task for testing each testable development deliverable for should we test a development task before marking it as complete?

Do we create separate testing tasks (which of course can not be started before the corresponding dev task is complete and will cause a certain task dependency and priority to develop) or do we simply consider a task complete once it's tested? How do we mark it on the board in the latter scenario?

Comment: What kind of testing are you talking about? Some testing, like unit testing, should not be decoupled from programming; they are a seamless whole. Also, what you describe doesn't sound like agile development at all. It sounds like you are doing iterative mini-waterfalls.

Comment: Integration (functional) tests, of course unit tests are handled by the same person who writes the code and kept/ran in Jenkins. I am interested in how the standard recommends this to happen. In my on-line search for an answer I keep finding contradictory results (If testing tasks are created separately, we will then have a task dependency to keep track of; if we include testing as a definition of DONE, we have to add more possible statuses for tasks: To Do, In Progress, In Tests, Done). Which is the recommended way?

Answer (score 1):

> Should we create a task for testing each testable development
>   deliverable for should we test a development task before marking it as
>   complete?

You should be testing a task before marking it as complete, otherwise it may become difficult to assess the state of a particular development task.

Additionally, it creates and artificial disconnected between your development tasks and the information they contain (such as user story, developer, any clarifications or discussions held on that task), and your test task (which may have it's own clarifications and discussions).

Testing is very much a two way process, so the tester should have knowledge of decisions the developer has made, and likewise the developer should see what the testers plan for testing is.

Our testers and developers discuss a task during planning, and the tester or developer will write some short QA Notes into the task upfront. Again keeping the testing activity and the development activity in the same place increases visibility across the two disciplines.

> How do we mark it on the board in the latter scenario?

How we manage it, is to capture untested tasks and tested tasks as different states the ticket are in. We use jira, and have created a workflow with the following states:

```
ToDo -> InProgress -> PullRequested -> Merged -> Resolved
```

- **ToDo**: in the sprint backlog, ready to be worked on.
- **InProgress**: Developer actively working on task
- **PullRequested**: PullRequest open in git for team review
- **Merged**: Merged into feature branch and deployed to test environment. It's at this point that a tester will pick it up and test.
- **Resolved**: Tester has tested and accepted this task.

If a tester finds an issue with the task, he/she will put the tasks back into the ToDo state, and notify the developer of issues found. Keeping the testing activity captured in the dev tasks like this allows us to track the number of these 'reopens', with high levels of reopens being a sign of poor quality reaching the test team - an indicator of a problems.

Tim

Answer (score 0):

The reason why there will be many contradictions in your online search results is that the solution to this problem depends very much on context, and on the state of the team. This is an area where the team is expected to self-organize around the problem.

When your org and team is in a state in which a kind of task is expected to come at a given "stage", creating a column on your scrum board is effective. However, as your org and team become more agile, columns on your scrum board should *collapse*, and the number of concurrently open stories should shrink. Roles will disappear, and they will be doing work more organically and collaboratively.